# Python-3: Why this following code returns none in print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

The below is my code:

```
lst=list()

n= int(input())

for i in range(n):
    s=input('Enter a String ')
    v=lst.append(s)
    print(v)
```

Why this following code returns none in print statement?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: because `append` doesn't return anything.

Comment: print lst instead of v

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you do `v = lst.append(s)` it returns none.

Solution:

```
lst=list()

n= int(input())

for i in range(n):
    s=input('Enter a String ')
    lst.append(s)
    print(lst)
```

Moreover, this code can be written even shorter:

```
print([i for i in [input() for j in range(int(input()))]])
```

Comment: If this is your answer upvote it and accept it so, others can find it easily

Comment: The longer version is much more readable code. Remember: Beautiful is better than ugly.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
lst.append(s)
print(lst)
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that .append will not return the list that is being appended. None is being stored in v.

By simplifying, you can maybe prevent errors. This can be simplified like so:

> > > print([input('Enter a string') for i in range(0, int(input('Enter a number')))])

This looks complicated, but is actually a shorthand version of a loop, called a *List Comprehension*. It is often used to create new lists. You can even add a condition to the end. Check it out!

> > > new_list = [expression(i) for i in old_list if filter(i)]

or **[i for i in i if i]** if you want to sound funny!

There are three parts.

1.*expression(i)* is what is being added to the list each time it loops.

2.*for i in old_list* is your typical for loop.

3.Add an *if* to the end if you like!

Because this creates a new [list], you can return, print, or store in a variable.